# How to connect Liferay 6.2 bundled with JBoss with MySQL db?

Tags: mysql, liferay

I'm a newbie in Liferay. 
I downloaded Liferay Portal 6.2 CE GA1 bundled with JBoss 7. As my understand, it, by default, connects to HSQL database, how can I change the connection to MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start Liferay for the first time your browser will open with an installer. That installer lets you select a different DBMS. But you will need to create the database manually before you run the installer, this will not be done by Liferay:

[image]